# dnsmasq not working when plugging in wired network

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

When connecting my Dell XPS13 laptop to a wired network via a Dell WD15 docking station, I'm unable to use the internet.

I've identified that it's a DNS issue and dnsmasq is misbehaving. Killing dnsmasq (which automatically starts a new process) solves the problem temporarily.

The problem doesn't occur with a wireless connection. Note that the laptop doesn't have a build-in ethernet port. A wired connect is always done through the USB-C port.

Disabling dnsmasq would be a workaround, but I prefer not to do that.

```
enxd481d72d354a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:81:d7:2d:35:4a  
          inet addr:192.168.224.125  Bcast:192.168.224.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8bdf:9a83:50e9:c4b4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1329 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1399042 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:405167 (405.1 KB)
```

How can I solve this, without disabling dnsmasq altogether?

Comment: what's the output of `grep -i interface /etc/dnsmasq.conf`?

Comment: Are you sure it's dnsmasq and not avahi? You could try to avoid all this by setting up static IP for this device. It would also tell you whether or not the problem truly lies where you think it does.

Comment: There is no **/etc/dnsmasq.conf**. dnsmasq is managed by the network-manager.

Comment: @user633551 Yes I'm sure it's dnsmasq. Restarting dnsmasq solves the issue, so does editing `/etc/resolv.conf` to connect to `8.8.8.8` directly.

Comment: No answers? :-( What a waste of a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have also started playing with firewall rules, they may be interfering with dnsmasq.

I would direct you to [my discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81107/why-must-loopback-traffic-be-authorized-using-iptables-to-get-web-access/295903#295903) of how iptables can interfere with local dns.